# Case statement will not display a varchar

Tags: sql, case, varchar

I need to pass a varchar through a case statement in SQL. The Current data is an integer but I would like to display text.

```
CASE b.religious_belief
WHEN 01 THEN 'none'     
WHEN 05 THEN 'roman catholic'    
 ELSE 0 
END
```

I keep getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

Comment: Can you post your whole SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All returned values from the CASE clauses should be strings (`varchar`)

```
CASE b.religious_belief
    WHEN 01 THEN 'none'     
    WHEN 05 THEN 'roman catholic'    
    ELSE 'Jedi' 
END as MyColumnName
```

Comment: Can you name the column that displays the data from the case??@mitch wheat

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE b.religious_belief
    WHEN 01 THEN 'none'     
    WHEN 05 THEN 'roman catholic'    
    ELSE '' 
END
```

The return for the `else` also needs to be a varchar, so if you're after a "zero" value, then either `''` or `null` would be best.